# XML to Dictionary using Linq To XML

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Ok I'm at lost on this simple thing.
I want to transform this xml to a dictionary, basically like that:

```
var xml = "<root><Hello>World</Hello><Foo>Bar</Foo></root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var elem in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    dic[elem.Name.LocalName] = elem.Value;
}
```

But I wanted to use ToDictionary, so I wrote this:

```
var dic = doc.Root.Elements().ToDictionary<string, string>(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => e.Value);
```

But it does not compile ! I get these errors

> Error 1   Instance argument: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'  Program.cs  65  22
>   Error 2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer)' has some invalid
>   arguments Program.cs  65  22   Error  3   Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'lambda expression' to 'System.Func'   Program.cs  65  71
>   Error 4   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer'    Program.cs  65  94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
var dic = doc.Root.Elements().ToDictionary<string, string>(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => e.Value);
```

should be like this:

```
var dic = doc.Root.Elements().ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => e.Value);
```

You don't have to state the type of key and the type of value. Please for further documenation on this have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549277(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I thought the types were optional, I guess I was confused as you don't write them at all...